# Firebase Type Safe Queries

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I'm using TypeScript and the Firebase 9.x SDK to query Firestore:

```
const q = query(myCollectionRef);
const snapshot = await getDocs(q);
snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
    console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
});
```

This returns me a generic `QuerySnapshot<DocumentData>`. Is there any way I can type this to a specific interface I have defined for my data - `QuerySnapshot<MyType>`?

If I try:

```
const q = query<MyType>(myCollectionRef);
const snapshot = await getDocs<MyType>(q);
```

TypeScript borks with:

```
TS2345: Argument of type 'CollectionReference<DocumentData>' is not assignable to 
   parameter of type 'Query<MyType>'.   Types of property 'converter' are 
   incompatible.     
Type 'FirestoreDataConverter<DocumentData> | null' is not 
   assignable to type 'FirestoreDataConverter<MyType> | null'.       
Type 'FirestoreDataConverter<DocumentData>' is not assignable to type 
   'FirestoreDataConverter<MyType>'.         
The types returned by 'fromFirestore(...)' are incompatible between these types. 
Type 'DocumentData' is not assignable to type 'MyType'.
```

Answer (score 0):

The common scenario is to use JavaScript `Date` type in interfaces, at the same time Firebase stores date fields with special `Firebase.Timestamp` type. There is a need to convert them back and force.

The [firestore-timestamp-converter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firestore-timestamp-converter) npm package was created exactly for this. It will also convert results to the `MyType` after `.withConverter()` usage:

```
const q = query(myCollectionRef).withConverter(new TimestampConverter<MyType>());
const snapshot = await getDocs(q);
```

---

Alternatively, cast `Query<>` to your type:

```
const q = query(myCollectionRef) as Query<MyType>;
const snapshot = await getDocs(q);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom converter and a custom database handler so you can use  types as you're trying to:

```
const converter = <T>() => ( {
  toFirestore: ( data: any ) => data,
  fromFirestore: ( doc: any ) =>
    doc.data() as T
} )
export const firestore = Object.assign(
  () => {
    return admin.firestore()
  }, {
  doc: <T>( path: string ) => {
    return admin.firestore()
      .doc( path )
      .withConverter<T>( converter<T>() )
  },
  collection: <T>( path: string ) => {
    return admin.firestore()
      .collection( path )
      .withConverter<T>( converter<T>() )
  }
} )
```

Then import and use it like this:

```
const query = firestore.doc<MyType>('path/to/doc')
```

It's the same for collections queries.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score -1):

What the error says is `DocumentData` is wider than `MyType`, hence you cannot assign `myCollectionRef`(CollectionReference) to `query<MyType>`

for read operation, an easy solution is to type cast `doc.data()` only, that would save you a lot of headache, you just need to type it everytime

but keep in mind firestore changed your data type, for example, changing servertimestamp, timestamp and date to timestamp

so you need to prepare at least 3 types for each model, one for query, one for read, one for write

properly type safe firestore is painful, you can use my library [FirelordJS](https://github.com/tylim88/FirelordJS)

it is the best Firestore type safety library at the moment (you are welcomed to prove me wrong)